# Symblog, количество комментариев

Tags: symfony, комментарии

Пытаюсь создать блог на Symfony 2 по учебнику
http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/.

В части 5 показано, как выводить количество комментариев под
каждым постом: `<p>Comments: {{ blog.comments|length }}</p>`
Но моя Doctrine 2 постоянно выводит 0, что неправильно:
http://clip2net.com/s/6bbulz

Где искать и в чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте перед выводом  {{ blog.comments|length }} что-нибудь вроде {{ dump(blog.comments) }}, чтобы посмотреть, есть ли у вас вообще комментарии.

Comment: этот ответ должен быть комментарием